# GeoServer REST API seed truncation

Tags: geowebcache, geoserver-rest-api

GeoServer version 2.18.0 running under Java 1.8.0-131 on a Windows machine.

I am trying to use the GeoServer REST API to seed GeoWebCache. I can get the seed process to commence and can follow its progress using the commands documented. My problem is that I am unable to stop the seeding process once it has started. I have tried the following methods as detailed in the seeding and truncating section of the manual.

1. Kill the task for a specific layer. POST command of the form :

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/rest/seed/MYStore:MYLayer

The above line returns 400 - bad request

Various attempts to provide some body for the POST also fail. I have tried JSON of the form
{ seedRequest : { "name" : "MYStore:MYLayer" }}  or the equivalent XML.

2. Kill all tasks

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/rest/seed

This returns - Chunk[] is not a valid entry

3. Using the kill all option as documented (curl attempt shown)

```
curl -v -u username:password -d "kill_all=all" "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/rest/seed"
```

This returns chunk [] is not a valid entry

I have no difficulty kill the seeding task using the GeoServer web interface.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the workspace & layer to the end of your kill_all command like so:

```
curl -v -u username:password -d "kill_all=all" "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/rest/seed/workspace:layername.xml"
```